# How to write SQL to calculate running average with some additional formulae?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssas

Following is the image that has running average calculated by me. But the requirement is a bit extra on top of the running average.

[image: Running average calculated already]

Following is the image where the requirement is in the Microsoft Excel sheet.

[image: Requirement on top of running average]

So, in order to calculate the running average with formulae like =**(3*C4+2*C5+1*C6)/6** that have been gathered in excel sheet, what SQL Query could be written?

Also, if it's not feasible through SQL, then how could I use the Column D from the second image as my measure in SSAS?

Comment: Why is your running average not including the second row?

Comment: As its your first post, can you please avoid using images for data, code and queries. Instead use formatted text. Not only does your question look better, is easier to read, but people trying to assist you can copy and paste code/data out of your question in order to improve/test it.

Comment: @gotqn Thank you for looking. That second row can be ignored. What I want to achieve is the data I get in the column D from the requirement screenshot.  instead of normal average, it requires to calculate using the formula as mentioned.

Comment: @DaleK Yes, I'll keep that in mind from next question. Thank you for the suggestion, I see it makes sense.

Comment: Its not too late for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `LAG()` with `offset` and follow your formula accordingly

```
avg_val = ( (3.0 * lag(Open_, 2) over (order by M, [WEEK]) )
          + (2.0 * lag(Open_, 1) over (order by M, [WEEK]) )
          + (1.0 * Open_) ) / 6
```